# Using “badblocks” on modern disks

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-blocks

I want to use badblocks to check my HDDs and would appreciate clarification of its operation.

Can someone please explain the best options to use with `-b` and `-c`? I have included their definitions from the man page, but am not sure if larger sizes would be beneficial for modern disks with 64MB RAM and 4k sectors.

```
-b block-size       Specify the size of blocks in bytes. The default is 1024. 
-c number of blocks the number of blocks which are tested at a time. The default is 64
```

Secondly I would like to know if the write-mode test is any more thorough than the non-destructive read-write mode?

Lastly how many SMART sector re-allocations are acceptable / should drives with non-zero reallocation counts be immediately replaced?

Comment: for 2nd part: as soon as you start to see badblocks, it means something went wrong. This is probably a good sign you should replace the disk before you can't read it at all. But in all cases, before even failure, you should always have 2 backups of important data (1 local, 1 remote) in addition to the working copy. see details on my answer there: http://superuser.com/a/528181/174998

Comment: for block size: it should reflect the actual block size your OS was using to store data on that hard drive (according to the filesystem used). It's not to speed things up, it's so that it it marks a block "bad", that block is indeed 1 block, and not 1/2 or 1/4th or even 2  (or more) blocks.

Answer (score 23):

**Question 1:**

With regards to the `-b` option: this depends on your disk. Modern, large disks have 4KB blocks, in which case you should set `-b 4096`. You can get the block size [from the operating system](https://superuser.com/questions/121252/how-do-i-find-the-hardware-block-read-size-for-my-hard-drive), and it's also usually obtainable by either reading the disk's information off of the label, or by googling the model number of the disk. If `-b` is set to something larger than your block size, the integrity of `badblocks` results can be compromised (i.e. you can get false-negatives: no bad blocks found when they may still exist). If `-b` is set to something smaller than the block size of your drive, the speed of the `badblocks` run can be compromised. I'm not sure, but there may be other problems with setting `-b` to something smaller than your block size, since it isn't verifying the integrity of an entire block, it might still be possible to get false-negatives if it's set too small.

The `-c` option corresponds to how many blocks should be checked at once. Batch reading/writing, basically. This option does not affect the integrity of your results, but it does affect the speed at which `badblocks` runs. `badblocks` will (optionally) write, then read, buffer, check, repeat for every N blocks as specified by `-c`. If `-c` is set too low, this will make your `badblocks` runs take much longer than ordinary, as queueing and processing a separate IO request incurs overhead, and the disk might also impose additional overhead per-request. If `-c` is set too high, `badblocks` might run out of memory. If this happens, `badblocks` will fail fairly quickly after it starts. Additional considerations here include parallel `badblocks` runs: if you're running `badblocks` against multiple partitions on the same disk (bad idea), or against multiple disks over the same IO channel, you'll probably want to tune `-c` to something sensibly high given the memory available to `badblocks` so that the parallel runs don't fight for IO bandwidth and can parallelize in a sane way.

**Question 2:**

Contrary to what other answers indicate, **the `-w` write-mode test is not more or less reliable than the non-destructive read-write test, but it is twice as fast, at the cost of being destructive to all of your data.** I'll explain why:

In non-destructive mode, `badblocks` does the following:

1. Read existing data, checksum it (read again if necessary), and store it in memory.
2. Write a predetermined pattern (overrideable with the `-p` option, though usually not necessary) to the block.
3. Read the block back, verifying that the read data is the same as the pattern.
4. Write the original data back to the disk.

   - I'm not sure about this, but it also probably re-reads and verifies that the original data was written successfully and still checksums to the same thing.

In destructive (`-w`) mode, `badblocks` only does steps 2 and 3 above. This means that the number of read/write operations needed to verify data integrity is cut in half. If a block is bad, the data will be erroneous in either mode. Of course, if you care about the data that is stored on your drive, you should use non-destructive mode, as `-w` will obliterate all data and leave `badblocks`' patterns written to the disk instead.

Caveat: if a block is *going* bad, but isn't completely gone yet, some read/write verification pairs may work, and some may not. In this case, non-destructive mode may give you a more reliable indication of the "mushiness" of a block, since it does two sets of read/write verification (maybe--see the bullet under step 4). Even if non-destructive mode is more reliable in that way, it's only more reliable *by coincidence*. The correct way to check for blocks that aren't fully bad but can't sustain multiple read/write operations is to run `badblocks` multiple times over the same data, using the`-p` option.

**Question 3:**

If SMART is reallocating sectors, you should probably consider replacing the drive ASAP. Drives that lose a few sectors don't *always* keep losing them, but the cause is usually a heavily-used drive getting magnetically mushy, or failing heads/motors resulting in inaccurate or failed reads/writes. The final decision is up to you, of course: based on the value of the data on the drive and the reliability you need from the systems you run on it, you might decide to keep it up. I have some drives with known bad blocks that have been spinning with SMART warnings for years in my fileserver, but they're backed up on a schedule  such that I could handle a total failure without much pain.

Comment: Any idea why `-b` defaults to `1024`?  That seems kind of weird to me.  Why not `512`?

Comment: @RyanJ 1024 is the minimum block size for `ext2`.  badblocks is part of e2fsprogs, and was originally intended to populate the bad blocks list of an ext2 filesystem.  You have to run it with the same blocksize as the FS to get the numbers in the right format for mkfs.ext2.  TL;DR: historical reasons which you should not be concerned with.

Comment: BUUUTT, @Zac B said "If -b is set to something larger than your block size, the integrity of badblocks results can be compromised"  1024 > 512.  I can understand how 513 might cause some bytest to go unchecked.  But perhaps it should be restated "If -b is set to something larger than your block size AND NOT AN EVEN MULTIPLE THEREOF, the integrity of badblocks results can be compromised".  What do you say original poster, other folks smarter than me?

Answer (score 4):

1) If your modern disk uses sector size other then 512b - then you need to set that size with `-b` option (i.e. `-b 4096`). Without that option your check will run much slower as each real sector will be tryied multiple times (8 times in case of 4k sector). Also as mentioned Olivier Dulac in comment to question - `block is indeed 1 block, and not 1/2 or 1/4th or even 2 (or more) blocks.`

Option `-c` imply on how many sectors tryid at once. It could have some implication on performance and value of that performance could depend on specific disk model.

2) `write-mode test` - In my understanding it will only check if you have hard-bad error or soft-bad error (aka Silent Data Degradation, bit rot, decay of storage media, UNC sectors)

3) I would not trust to SMART report at point in time. It is more important how values changes through time. Also here is research by Google [Failure Trends in a Large Disk Drive Population](http://research.google.com/archive/disk_failures.pdf) and here is some [discussion](http://storagemojo.com/2007/02/19/googles-disk-failure-experience/) of it. Here is cite from research:

> Despite this high correlation, we conclude that models based on SMART
>   parameters alone are unlikely to be useful for predicting individual
>   drive failures.

Regarding mentions by other for disk replacement - you may have not hard-bad disk problem but Silent Data Degradation (bit rot, decay of storage media,UNC sectors). In that case it has no sense to replace disk, but instead it is useful to perform read/write of same data back to disk. You could look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/642670/tool-to-read-all-blocks-from-hdd-and-write-it-back) how it could be resolved.

If you have  hard-bad error you could try to repartition drive in the way that bad area is located out of any partitions. For me that approach was useful and such bad drive was used for long time without any problems.

Comment: First sentence is wrong, `-b` defaults to 1024. If your disk uses a sector size other than 1024, which is pretty common outside of ext2 filesystems, then you should specify that.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave -b and -c as default unless you have a specific reason to change them.
You could probably set -b to 4096 if your disk has 4k block sizes.

I would suggest you first run badblocks with non-destructive rw test. If it finds any bad sectors, the disk is broken and should be replaced. If it does NOT find any bad blocks on non-destructive, but you still suspect it to have badblocks, then run the destructive rw test.

> Lastly how many SMART sector re-allocations are acceptable / should
>   drives with non-zero reallocation counts be immediately replaced?

I would replace the drive as soon as sectors are being replaced.

Comment: _I would replace the drive as soon as sectors are being replaced._ how do you know that blocks are going bad in normal operation? Do you get a signal in some way?

Comment: You have to monitor SMART logs.

Comment: _unless you have a specific reason to change them_. Like having a block size different from the default 1024, which is very common?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of goes to the difference between badblocks read mode (non-destructive) and write mode (destructive):

A drive will only reallocate a bad sector when a write fails.  Read errors for files only get "corrected" when an attempt is made to re-write the file.  Otherwise. the bad block remains part of the file on the assumption that you might be able to recover something. Read errors for partition tables can only be "corrected" by running bad blocks in write mode and recreating the partition

So, read mode will tell you where the bad blocks are but can't do anything about them.  Write mode tests the health of each sector and will cause the disk to re-allocate a bad block but at the expense of destroying the data.  Take your pick.

Comment: This isn't correct.  Non-destructive mode writes to the disk *twice* as many times as destructive mode.

Comment: Absolutely correct for GOOD sectors.  badblocks doesn't attempt to re-write failed read sectors in non-destructive mode.  Attempting to write the data back to a failed sector causes the disk to re-map the sector from spares and, voila, any data on the bad sector is lost.  A failed write after a good read simply causes the disk to remap the sector and all is good.  This approach actually makes sense if you want the disk to do the best it can to preserve data.  The data in a failed sector MAY be recoverable with a hex editor so leaving failed read sectors alone is the least destructive approach.

Comment: `badblocks` destructive mode: 1. writes random data to the disk, then 2. reads it back.  `badblocks` nondestructive mode: 1. reads data from the disk 2. writes random data to the disk 3. reads the random data back 4. writes the original data back.  So nondestructive is not "read only mode"; it writes twice as many times.

Comment: Almost correct. badblocks sort of follows the process you describe (writes are specific paterns; not random) when the read is good for non-destructive.  It does NOT write the data back if the read is bad. Same set of patterns are used for destructive. Just no attempt to read. The problem is that disks only remap bad sectors after a failed write which doesn't happen in non-destructive mode.

Comment: `(writes are specific paterns; not random)` Right, I use `-t random`, but the point is the number of writes, not the pattern. `It does NOT write the data back if the read is bad.` OK… But it *usually* writes the original data back, when the disk is good, which is why it's non-destructive. `Just no attempt to read.` Huh?  Are you saying the manual is wrong? Destructive mode writes `some patterns on every block of the device, reading every block and comparing the contents.`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question about remapped sectors, it depends. I'm speaking from the context of a home user who (occasionally) monitors this kind of stuff.

- How critical is the data stored on the drive?
- What is lost if the drive suddenly goes belly up?
- Is the data backed up elsewhere?
- Is the drive a member of a RAID where loss of the drive has minimal impact?
- Is the number of remapped sectors growing?

Here are two situations I faced. I had a RAID5 of 6 200GB drives. After a power failure that resulted in flickering lights, one drive showed 14 remapped sectors and logged several errors. I watched the drive and no more errors were logged and the remapped sector count remained stable. I concluded that the drive suffered due to a power transient and was not otherwise failing. I continued using it for years. The original RAID5 was retired but I have two of those drives in service with about 10 years of power on hours. They have a handful of remapped sectors. I use two of them mirrored to store incremental backup dumps from my primary backup. That way the main backup is seeing (mostly) read operations and the writes are going to different devices. If one of these ancient drives fails, The other should keep on going. If both fail, I replace them with something else and rerun the backup script. Impact if one of these drives fails is near zero so I don't worry about remapped sectors.

I had a 2TB HDD that was one of a pair of mirrored drives and which started to grow remapped sectors. At first it was dozens, then hundreds, then thousands. This was over a period of years. The other drive in the pair remained healthy and in fact, the slowly failing derive was not dropped from the array. Eventually I replaced both drives with 6TB drives and the growing remapped sector count became a non-issue. I still have the drive and it still "works," even with about 4500 remapped sectors. I have put drives like this in a test system (as a RAID member) to see what happens when one actually dies. I have had a couple opportunities to work with this and in all circumstances the replacement went without drama.

I did have a drive fail on my primary backup file server. It produced no advanced warning, it just stopped responding to SATA commands. It was a member of a ZFS RAIDZ2 and I replaced it without any drama. In fact, on my test server I have replaced failing drives without power cycling or rebooting the server.

One more point to note, I have on site and off site backups of all important data. If any one system is lost, there are two copies of the data elsewhere.