# Why do the same files show as different sizes on a USB and the hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, file-transfer, ubuntu-16.04

I copied the folder on the right (which is on a flash drive) to my desktop (the folder on the left). Both have the same number of items, and there were no errors during the copy so I'm assuming that there wasn't an early exit during copying a file. But for some reason the flash drive version is about 100MB larger.

[image]

Does Ubuntu do some kind of auto-compression? Is it to do with the disk format?

Comment: Could be due to different block sizes: http://superuser.com/questions/121252/how-do-i-find-the-hardware-block-read-size-for-my-hard-drive